# Postgres trigger that inserts in a secondary table - sometimes seem to not work

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I have a main table, let's call it A.
And a trigger.

```
create trigger my_trigger
    after insert or update or delete
    of column1, column2
    on "A"
    for each row
execute procedure trigger_logic();
```

```
create function trigger_logic() returns trigger
    language plpgsql
as
$$
DECLARE
    reference_id varchar;
BEGIN
    IF TG_OP = 'DELETE' then
        reference_id = OLD.id;
    ELSE
        reference_id = NEW.id;
    END IF;
    INSERT INTO B (reference)
    SELECT reference_id
        WHERE NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM B
        WHERE reference = reference_id
    );
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$;
```

Overall works well, but then on several times I ended up with one row in table A and no corresponding row in table B, even if I run afterwards the query with "WHERE NOT EXISTS" and it should have inserted it.

I have 1 million correct record pairs and around 10 with no entry in table B.

I don't really understand how this is possible. Isn't the trigger transactional with the operation in table A. Is there any situation in which this could happened. I also checked the postgres logs and didn't see anything out of the ordinary.

Comment: You mean you inserted 1 million rows into A, and when checking immediately after, 10 of them were missing from B? Or has this database existed for some time, and now that you investigate a problem, you found 10 missing rows? In the latter case, the trigger might have been turned off for some time, or they might have been DELETEd from B after the trigger inserted them.

Comment: Are you doing  UPDATEs that do not include the  `column1, column2` fields? If so then the trigger will not fire.

Comment: @Bergi 1 week interval, 1 million rows inserts into A, after 1 week I figured out, 10 of them were missing from B.

Comment: I am 100 percent sure, they weren't deleted.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver checked, the inserted rows in table A, all that columns populated. The row in table B, was missing after INSERTs.